# PDF to Single, Continuous JPG

Tags: pdf, convert, imagemagick, jpeg

I'm looking for a way to convert a PDF to a single, continuous JPG.  I've tried:

```
convert source.pdf output.jpg
```

But I get all separate pages, eg:

```
output-1.jpg output-2.jpg output-3.jpg ...
```

Is there something I'm missing, so that all my pages will be laid out vertically in the resulting JPG, rather than each page to its own jpg?

Comment: `convert source.pdf -append output.jpg` makes a single, vertically tiled JPEG for me.

Comment: @muru I was going to add that I was able to -append the outputted JPGs after the initial convert statement.  This gave me a oneliner.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to skip outputting all the pages to respective JPGs, one must -append in the statement.  My final, working statement is

```
convert -density 300 -append source.pdf output.jpg
```

Comment: Does not work for me

Comment: convert: not authorized `00a61701-70a4-4d27-802c-ce5a1a864621.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/412.
convert: no images defined `output.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3210.

Comment: @ArunGowda in your `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` change `<policy domain="coder" rights="none" pattern="PDF" />` ----to---> `<policy domain="coder" rights="read|write" pattern="PDF" />`

Comment: Don't disable ImageMagick's security checks to make this work. Use other software where security comes by default.

Comment: It's working good for me.